# Midi playback to same device

Tags: midi

So guys my question may sound familiar but the thing is not exactly the help I need.
So I have a piano and my piano sends a MIDI signal throughout a USB To host cable and I'm looking for either two of these ways,

1. I want to open a midi file and it sends it's midi signal to my same computer that I'm using as a midi device it self.
2. or send this midi signal to my piano and play it back in my computer at the same time.

So I'm looking for someone who can tell me a kind of program to do that or else I can do it my self if it is not going to trouble my time, I have learned only Java and Visual Basic, please assist me with a helpful answer.

:)

Answer (score 1):

Any sequencer software should be able to allow you to take a midi input and also send audio to an internal synth. However, if you need to use a standalone synth software, you might find a virtual midi port is required.

Windows: 
http://www.nerds.de/en/loopbe1.html

OSx allows you to define them without additional software:
http://www.johanlooijenga.com/tools/12-virtual-ports.html

Depending on your setup, you may be able to use a virtual midi port alone to do what you are attempting.